# Scraping a webpage with all the variants for a particular product with BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am having difficulty in displaying the product list. I want to scrape the data from a webpage. Since I am very very much new to Python and Webscraping. The `print(productlist)` is not working.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

baseurl = "https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com"
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML,  like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36'}

k = requests.get('https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/35/japanese-whisky')
soup=BeautifulSoup(k.text,'html.parser')
productlist = soup.find_all("li",{"class":"product-grid__item"})
print(productlist)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your usage of BeautifulSoup. The problem lies within the site: it is protected by [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/), and attempts to scrape the site will be faced with a [JavaScript challenge](https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/known-issues-and-faq/#general), a form of CAPTCHA.

In this case, there is not much you can do to bypass CloudFlare.

You can verify this by using `curl`: `curl -L https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com`. In the response, you can see this:

```html
<span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span>
```

which is a sign that your scraper is being blocked.

And as @nejdetckenobi said, the website uses JavaScript to load the products, so the components would not load with `requests`. The following is an example using `selenium` instead:

```py
from selenium import webdriver as wd
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import By
import time

URL = 'https://www.thewhiskyexchange.com/c/35/japanese-whisky'


def main():
    driver = wd.Chrome(wd.ChromeOptions())

    driver.implicitly_wait(20)
    driver.get(URL)

    time.sleep(5)

    products = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-card__name')

    print([p.text for p in products])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Learn more about `selenium` with the documentation [here](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You are using BeautifulSoup correct :)
But You will need to access this webpage in another way then a simple request.get()

Because what you a looking for in `productlist` aka  `{"class":"product-grid__item"}` is not part of the returned string in `k.text`

You can check `k.text` contents using another print like such `print(f"k.text contains: {k.text}")`

For me this yeilds the following sting.
Maybe you need to look at another link or using another tool for your product-grid__item, as it is not part of your current k.text.

For your clue of what is wrong, look in the returned k.text:

```
<span id="challenge-error-text">Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue</span>
```

### k.text

> k.Text: Just a
> moment...Enable
> JavaScript and cookies to
> continue(function(){window._cf_chl_opt={cvId:
> '2',cZone: "www.thewhiskyexchange.com",cType: 'interactive',cNounce:
> '45162',cRay: '8098df96ecbfbe4c',cHash: '1cf80c6fbf1a491',cUPMDTk:
> "/c/35/japanese-whisky?__cf_chl_tk=VFxprfxk2K7uMv5y0LpXXlK_dih6FnMe3TwITIiFP6s-1695200377-0-gaNycGzNCfs",cFPWv:
> 'b',cTTimeMs: '1000',cMTimeMs: '0',cTplV: 5,cTplB: 'cf',cK:
> "visitor-time",fa:
> "/c/35/japanese-whisky?_*cf_chl_f_tk=VFxprfxk2K7uMv5y0LpXXlK_dih6FnMe3TwITIiFP6s-1695200377-0-gaNycGzNCfs",md:
> "5XihUl6T63j9F7hlv4wbmqggz9GgVMAO.1AgdNd9M60-1695200377-0-AT-SWJ4pLjfTHh1KwUSjMvpy6ktRTUDkrD4WDXOafPGNAsu8LEt3hYkTdc_tNxcaTST2AgYa4WU5vGgkAYB5yXRAEonsWe--er-AWe6ffER3PMXl692b2c6KA552e9ahh79FzxPvgDoioIXIK8EYafFjfq80nxBLiy55QfgvCxq425N4NSozOHA3nVkpHrOYpScH8FlkZAE4rEsSu_hMSGIw0Qd6pEV4FMwSlTAKF5AfVL_BgRAjcZE076Lb1Nxdfr89FI77XxvGnMjimmxXXGRSkHDGPfKGgF0RTAB90ETVVHOfl8W-Nh5pAjIZERSDGIu2v3Sf-GRCnfRtDj0IXIAMTvVS_aES8E0no9HYlhIPJ-XdAQDd5Dm6YNUN9SXOjoQYGX4G16wF0ka1HKbfW1GU64Q1F71uM-vnoFkrFOU2fC8hb1Y7T-xrDweMQCZg0b2vAy1Id2U3wZh7MO7bwgsJ35DmcuP60CjunWuXAP9bS1kgOXkhKks9a1RN5d4TJNSYIAK0S8WHPu3Y5rtz4jcoxSTAMPLNgkMA3lBxi2fl2Oa-fjxffzyXpQGBz3rnrH7YxDIx6w2PhMYSaPAMEV1VzmV61rd5uR3Fm_HKHGFV15V5JrEQ8m4_rtkW4IzBEh4wRg1KQZTFy8qHBiqooPxItOPcBaAGokDe7gYi2A5fxao7f8qilJ1MHghhW436rbg872ZL8OZDHzsI3z-y_QIjN5Ncpu2uUWjfHFGe-qStrMlusJp6-JidzsdfG9ERj0AWdfIwp2dLff6LbaoA4PwBKnJsvcSqt7E0KB3W0jyb8ulriSOb1mFzXl9STkn7u9arts_7qVVLJR82bN81dBwkyf0aoqc3nZK98i3dv8zDo_Q4OtWfayiUcj4uwZtMcupxXbxSim7T1llhDCbdsjh0GeiWNOKAL-iClod2ru-Iziq_IID8NzUM8RbGVl98Ooeiqa1AVHBmNBTg3Nno6vuRKJWGp5VlkaHfLX0rTUAr43kPiLxqkzJA88snXuaXc3hmFB_74z-ddRDYt1n6Jzm8i9NUtEk76hERfI_1TtoV9sR8MaNo0A8NXMulu_KdMpdZX2IyNs-lq_DonUgfsaZndO5zgSFChsPpqJOQClCIxnIze0pC5VTjqkeTQXQ__DkK4Mt1A8ubzLAkydDXzWyD_3ooToYaOZNeQuUlcrlwMzDi2fn1CB_tFRrAksVDNAhLP7a1WfDd768jLhCGrfG_SQxTfy7fhf-rGfH8U0flEQHda2SshfusSaurdOVCPI4cIgMznEUhHBdWBst79bIgXbpCa6A_53E8wNteOBYNhBsGGRrdh5Wh2tWe8cvwp7lP3f5tz9PG_555Rs6BZx-YKIh4t-IAtXDTS7E_BvwEayNhL8XWdWH-Bg074utgU_IdA7acHszhAMlXlm8GaWgTKw0WhDw6ipBJrtzcVY-pHALdJlBTXxfsPIsPE6oBNBhmVQTpeHpIFvq6V9ypwTxopgb8ySoYS17ViS0ZSSRbihLtGEoj8S-qBP8-Y_1Yhu_UhGLD9J5LKHza8R4Qar4-KUKaf7yfeKBm6MVTFEi_sqiMYGmjmfbv2QyXHHjAF3MYsRSMWQGQaP3XDJ_sl9j2Wd8_82cfUKwn9ut6EfmzRtiqTMTHA3jNIrt0qNZffIhBI8yjYpud5SGgK0AOrwGY_fCYXGnTek6Ez6Z7QdQf2N2sDJ3CMa8KaQvaG1KZbEwrcW3IBet32RA54pePEQHQOBgb1Fi4rUrp6TzwWhmOzd5TRmU52ep5hMqNZXrqkcAyCyTl0fJQFdDjlrI7zzjDZu_5BLVoQ1Va0PAZN-UxuR7aatPtO2HLAasKvDFkNabVwUpOw1ivOLvsRSUgKQIZYjTLdFyyfkVMut6fEMUH65lb89Y1MvEgn8aBriDLMuJ4zjbgU89khvxYikUGyza6Lj6BP7huIsDpxI3JeZU12-tVzUHkCBZVEjW9Z7kvGFOI20VfGRX4ukzNZ0an_PtF3AP-exf0zZ3zM9s73lpmJv3rQ1c8JP6COSRAxumgntEqUe1NfUs3RNm056WNSvRvdqtUisLaqBMw592bEc5hTQz_sQrmFakRt3r_prmDWd4PVw4dLmxrDkBXp0cLVzFCyDNK2rXneD9eLnaNpdzZaGtZ3fPBf1D1wilDyavdXCnn-ibDA4lGymdeRqwPKLV*-bZLv2m1dtnwpHb9K7KjfSUjFyyXfo4DbtYON5OOxSOHwsjMTFeEdhd31JT-_SamVuXkntC2mIutkJc20RvNkJ1Erf9crXYHRWy3muQdQQWZPartYMiLSFNn1jQs-5OA79zqQ0AcgDHE4jKNEEpP5QDqFZniOqrEhSl7pL_890eigayz1N_dmtSe62-2Py4c-J9ZB3zgsFjR7xk2z5B2xxgacVS7JDFss0XxahwdHyiGPhojh1ChlhF3H2qGy0yAMoqnm3eJRhLXRCBIWYKvwpXxG-fD4XZfSO2-OBRuDA",cRq:
> {ru:
> 'aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cudGhld2hpc2t5ZXhjaGFuZ2UuY29tL2MvMzUvamFwYW5lc2Utd2hpc2t5',ra:
> 'cHl0aG9uLXJlcXVlc3RzLzIuMzEuMA==',rm: 'R0VU',d:
> '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',t:
> 'MTY5NTIwMDM3Ny40MzkwMDA=',cT: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000),m:
> 'a2AsyNIN/NAij7HFCGrX3XvzT5X+w1ymY4tyAvbok+k=',i1:
> 'gUidhQr6vHAcLFLeJUIaGg==',i2: '78MQeBOnbKsIzIbpivDnGA==',zh:
> 'Lu11UPKpct80h4UpHjnFr7549vZ5EGi2V7KjmFdfcoc=',uh:
> 'YE9XOpG5TeHmhA1zfs5mxC8CrRZzq2a/+r+OU7dliYQ=',hh:
> '1iL0YmRIkuteIeg9zu2NzR9zkRexldgCzJYoCkFcSM8=',}};var cpo =
> document.createElement('script');cpo.src =
> '/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/b/orchestrate/chl_page/v1?ray=8098df96ecbfbe4c';window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash
> = location.hash === '' && location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1 ? '#' : location.hash;window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery = location.search === '' &&
> location.href.slice(0, location.href.length -
> window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash.length).indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '?' :
> location.search;if (window.history && window.history.replaceState)
> {var ogU = location.pathname + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUQuery +
> window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash;history.replaceState(null, null,
> "/c/35/japanese-whisky?__cf_chl_rt_tk=VFxprfxk2K7uMv5y0LpXXlK_dih6FnMe3TwITIiFP6s-1695200377-0-gaNycGzNCfs" + window._cf_chl_opt.cOgUHash);cpo.onload = function() {history.replaceState(null, null,
> ogU);}}document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cpo);}());